# Get ID of row where value is 'x' in ON clause

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT(journey.id), journey.departure
FROM journey
JOIN journey_day ON journey_day.journey = journey.id
JOIN pattern ON pattern.id = journey.pattern
JOIN pattern_link ON pattern_link.section = pattern.section
WHERE pattern.service = :service AND pattern.direction = :direction AND journey_day.day = :day
GROUP BY journey.id
HAVING SUM(pattern_link.from_stop = :arrival) > 0 and
       SUM(pattern_link.from_stop = :departure) > 0
ORDER BY journey.departure
```

Above I have a relatively simple MySQL query.

How can I change the above join of the `pattern_link` table so it effectively does the following:

"Join on the pattern's section being equal to the pattern_link's section (what it does at the moment), AND also where the ID is less than the row of the ID with the value "duck"

The bit I'm not sure how to do is the "where the ID is less than the row of the ID with the value "duck". How can I do this on the `pattern_link` join? It'd be fine if it was a specific ID, I could just say `ON id = 4`, but I need to get the ID of duck first so I'm not sure.

Thanks

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You can do it 2 ways, the simpler:

```
  SELECT j.id, j.departure
    FROM journey j
    JOIN journey_day jd 
      ON jd.journey = j.id
     AND jd.day = :day
    JOIN pattern p
      ON p.id = j.pattern
     AND p.direction = :direction 
     AND p.service = :service
    JOIN pattern_link pl 
      ON pl.section = p.section
     AND pl.id < (SELECT id FROM pattern_link WHERE value = 'duck')
GROUP BY j.id
  HAVING SUM(pl.from_stop = :arrival) > 0
     AND SUM(pl.from_stop = :departure) > 0
ORDER BY j.departure
```

Or the (almost certainly) faster:

```
  SELECT j.id, j.departure
    FROM journey j
    JOIN journey_day jd 
      ON jd.journey = j.id
     AND jd.day = :day
    JOIN pattern p
      ON p.id = j.pattern
     AND p.direction = :direction 
     AND p.service = :service
    JOIN pattern_link pl 
      ON pl.section = p.section
    JOIN pattern_link pl_duck
      ON pl_duck.id > pl.id
     AND pl_duck.value = 'duck'
GROUP BY j.id
  HAVING SUM(pl.from_stop = :arrival) > 0
     AND SUM(pl.from_stop = :departure) > 0
ORDER BY j.departure
```

Note; I removed the `DISTINCT` as it is negated by the `GROUP BY` and added aliases for my own preference/understanding.

I also put the table specific conditions in the `JOIN`s where I could.